# How to determine if a link is nofollow or dofollow in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

So, that was the question. I have a Scrapy bot that follows internal links of a given site, writes its links, status code and anchor text into database. But I'm struggling to grab the link's follow status. Is there any way to grab that `rel=nofollow/dofollow` information? That's my code if anybody wonders;

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'spydiiiii'
    start_urls = [urlToScrape]
    rules = (
        Rule (
            LxmlLinkExtractor(
                allow=(urlToScrape),
                deny=(
                    "google.com",
                    "facebook.com",
                    "pinterest.com",
                    "facebook.com",
                    "digg.com",
                    "twitter.com",
                    "stumbleupon.com",
                    "linkedin.com"
                ),
                unique=True

            ),
        callback="parse_items",
        follow= True,
        ),
    )



    def parse_items(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        items = []
        item = InternallinkItem()


        referring_url = response.request.headers.get('Referer').decode('utf-8')
        item["referring_url"] = referring_url

        anchor = response.meta.get('link_text')
        item["anchor_text"] = " ".join(anchor.split())

        item["current_url"] = response.url

        item['status'] = response.status

        items.append(item)
        return items
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can't get `nofollow` after you load this link. You can find it only in links on original page. I don't see any option in [LxmlLinkExtractor](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html) which could get this attribute and send to `parse_items`. Maybe you will have to write own `LinkExtractor`. It only allow to restrict links and then you could skip links with or without nofollow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `LxmlLinkExtractor` manually to get `Link` objects which have `nofollow` information.

In `parse()` I get links from first page and create item with 'nofollow' (and other) informations, and use `Requests` with this url (and with `item` in `meta`) to get `status` and `referer`.

New `Requests` uses `parse_item()` to get `item` from `meta` and add `status`.

`parse_item()` also uses extractor to get new links on this page and create new `item` and execute `Requests` with `parse_item()` again.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    #allowed_domains = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com']

    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com']
    #start_urls = ['http://127.0.0.1:5000/'] # for Flask example

    extractor = LxmlLinkExtractor(
                    allow=('http://quotes.toscrape.com'),
                    #allow=('http://127.0.0.1:5000'), # for Flask example
                    deny=(
                        'google.com',
                        'facebook.com',
                        'pinterest.com',
                        'facebook.com',
                        'digg.com',
                        'twitter.com',
                        'stumbleupon.com',
                        'linkedin.com'
                    ),
                    unique=True,
                )

    def parse(self, response):
        print('parse url:', response.url)

        # use LxmlLinkExtractor manually
        for link in self.extractor.extract_links(response):
            #print('link:', link)
            item = {}
            item['nofollow'] = link.nofollow
            item['anchor_text'] = link.text
            item['current_url'] = link.url
            #item['referring_url'] = response.url

            yield Request(link.url, meta={'item': item}, callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print('parse_item url:', response.url)

        item = response.meta['item']
        item['referring_url'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
        #item['referring_url'] = response.request.url
        item['status'] = response.status
        yield item

        # use LxmlLinkExtractor manually with new links
        for link in self.extractor.extract_links(response):
            #print('link:', link)
            item = {}
            item['nofollow'] = link.nofollow
            item['anchor_text'] = link.text
            item['current_url'] = link.url
            #item['referring_url'] = response.url

            yield Request(link.url, meta={'item': item}, callback=self.parse_item)

# --- run spider without project ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv',
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Because I don't know any page with `rel="nofollow"` so I created simple code in `Flask` to test code.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<a href="/test1" rel="nofollow">Test 1</a> | <a href="/test2">Test 2</a>'

@app.route('/test1')
def test1():
    return '<a href="/" rel="nofollow">Main Page</a>'

@app.route('/test2')
def test2():
    return '<a href="/">Main Page</a>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```